# pip or pip3 install command throwing error

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, visual-studio-2017, command

Whenever I run `pip install <PACKAGE-NAME>`. `cmd` throws an error. It is only when I run `pip install <PACKAGE-NAME> --user` the command prompt works properly without any error.

For instance, when I run `pip3 install runway-python`
I get, ERROR:

> Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py",
>   line 186, in _main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
>   line 258, in run
>       isolated_mode=options.isolated_mode,   File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
>   line 604, in decide_user_install
>       if site_packages_writable(root=root_path, isolated=isolated_mode):   File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
>   line 549, in site_packages_writable
>       test_writable_dir(d) for d in set(get_lib_location_guesses(**kwargs))   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
>   line 549, in 
>       test_writable_dir(d) for d in set(get_lib_location_guesses(**kwargs))   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\utils\filesystem.py",
>   line 140, in test_writable_dir
>       return _test_writable_dir_win(path)   File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\utils\filesystem.py",
>   line 153, in _test_writable_dir_win
>       fd = os.open(file, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\shared\python37_64\Lib\site-packages\accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_1epdye'

it's fine when I append the code with `--user`. is there a way to fix this?
I mean so that I don't have to append `every pip install` command with a `--user`.

Comment: Please use apropriate formatting for your error message. As it is, it is highly unreadable. I suggest code formatting (wrap it in three ` after pasting it to your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Errno+13+Permission+denied

Comment: `fishfingers` ??? 

Answer (score 0):

Your python installation (which seems to have come with visual studio) is under `'c:\program files (x86)`, which is by default only writeable with admin privileges. In order to get your `pip install` working, you will need to launch your cmd with admin privileges.

Comment: I tried cmd with admin privileges. It worked fine. 
do you have any other solution other than opening cmd in admin mode?

Comment: If you don't want to use `--user` each time and don't want to bother opening in admin mode each time, I only see two other ways: Modify the security settings so normal users have rw rights on `c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64` OR uninstall the visual studio python installation and instead download and install python yourself and install it for your user only

Comment: I don't want to recommend to mess with your security settings, so I would see option 2 as my recommendation if you want to get rid of bothering with the restrictions

Answer (score -3):

I suggest uninstalling and reinstalling pip:

```
sudo apt remove python-pip
sudo apt install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install -U pip
```

(Or the same with pip3 if that is what you're using)

Comment: OP is using windows, so no `sudo`, also, why do you think reinstalling will fix the issue that the `site-packages` requires admin privileges to write to